# Laravel Attach another relationship to existing Model object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My structure is the following

Posts -> Comments_Group -> Comments

I have created a Eloquent Model by - which I do some logic with:

```
$post = Post::find($post_id);
```

I want to return this objects "comments group" and "comments". I am trying something like this:

```
return $post->comments_group->with('comments');
```

But that does not work...

FYI - error message I get is:
"Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string"

Comment: Can you show me your post model ?

Comment: Do you want to see the relationships?

Comment: Yes comments_group method in your post model specifically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$post = Post::with('comments_group.comments')->find($post_id);
```

Or [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```
$post = Post::find($post_id);
....
$post->load('comments_group.comments');
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, needed to use both those methods ;-)